# Как обойти ошибку которая просит обновить страницу , если не знаешь в какой момент времени она может появится?Selenium+python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautiful-soup

Как обойти ошибку которая просит обновить страницу , если не знаешь в какой момент времени она может появиться?Selenium+python

заставить скрипт продолжить работу

Answer (score 0):

Ожидайте появление блока

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
pagination_block = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-pagination__item.b-pagination__item--next.js-pagination-next")))
```

Данный код в течении 10 секунд ожидает, что элемент с CSS-селектором расположен в дереве

Вообщем посмотрите пакет EC, там много параметров по какому действию ожидать элемент
(видим ли, возможно ли кликнуть, стал ли невидимым и т. д)

Comment: это окно появляется поверх сайта , и он может появится когда угодно , я не могу каждый раз ждать

Comment: Ну у вас на какое-то действие кинуло Exception, вы в обработке ошибки, запускаете метод, который и ищет этот элемент в течении 1 секунды, либо вообще не использовать ожидание